# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in an angular2 component function

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to navigate after some count down. Here is my code

```
 constructor(
     private router: Router
    ) {}


onsubmit(){
        //I call the count down function here
        this.countdown();
      }

countDown() {
        var i = 5;
         var myinterval = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "redirecting in: " + i;
            if (i === 0) {
                clearInterval(myinterval );
                 this.router.navigate(['/About']);
            }
            else {
                i--;
            }
        }, 1000);
     }
```

The count down displays fine but when it gets to the navigate part,
I get this error :

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

What is it am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Arrow function` in `setInterval` function, which would make Component `` `this`(context) available inside `setInterval` function.

**Code**

```
 var myinterval = setInterval(() => { //<-- user arrow function
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "redirecting in: " + i;
    if (i === 0) {
        clearInterval(myinterval );
         this.router.navigate(['/About']);
    }
    else {
        i--;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: A great solution.

Comment: Can you please help on this. Thanks ~Sudhir       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411836